# Xamarin Forms - Connect to remote DB when refreshing ListView

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am doing a reservation app and when the user refreshes the ListView it should connect to the remote DB to get all the reservations and update the ListView.

I have the code in my `onAppearing` method

I tried to add the following code to the refresh binding, with no luck:

```
       ItemsPage ip = new ItemsPage();
       ArrayList reservations = new ArrayList();
       reservations =  await ip.CheckReservations(ItemsPage.currentDate);
       ItemsPage.reservations = reservations;
```

The code for the connection to the DB in the `OnAppearing()` void

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        reservations = new ArrayList();
        reservations = await CheckReservations(currentDate);
    }
```

The binding for refresh:

```
      public class ItemsViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Termin> Items { get; set; }
    public Command LoadItemsCommand { get; set; }

    public ItemsViewModel()
    {
        Title = "Rezervácie";
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Termin>();
        LoadItemsCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadItemsCommand());
    } 

    async Task ExecuteLoadItemsCommand()
    {

        if (IsBusy)
            return;

        IsBusy = true;
        try
        {

            var items = await DataStore.GetItemsAsync(true);
            foreach (var item in items)
            {

                Items.Add(item);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }


    }
}}
```

The GetItemsAsync:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Termin>> GetItemsAsync(bool forceRefresh = false)
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(items);
    }
```

ItemsPage is my view.

The refresh method is called in my viewModel.
Navigating to another page and refreshing works.

After doing a reservation I call:

```
 ItemsListView.BeginRefresh();
```

And that does work, but referencing that line from the refresh command makes the LV not populating.

The XAML code:

```
   <ListView x:Name="ItemsListView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            HasUnevenRows="true"
            BackgroundColor="DarkGreen" 
            SeparatorColor="Black"
            RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}"
            IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
            IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
            CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
            ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
```

Comment: 1. You want to refresh binding in `onappearing`, however `reservations` there has no relationship with `Items` or `listview`, how can you refresh binding? 2. What do you mean by  `referencing that line from the refresh command makes the LV not populating`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your List of objects in the ViewModel should be am ObservableCollection, so that the list detects the changes in the List and update the UI accordingly.

In your model:

```
 public ObservableCollection<YourModel> ListViewItems { get; set; }
```

In XAML

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListViewItems}" />
```

Comment: Items are  `Items = new ObservableCollection<Termin>();`

Comment: update your question with all the relevant code. Not just pieces.

Comment: OnAppearing is updating a local ArrayList, while your Refresh command is updating an ObservableCollection is your VM.  Which is your ListView actually bound to?

Comment: Updated my OP, added the xaml bindings to the end.